# mysqli update with parameter binding not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to build a reusable function to update a row in a table, using a prepared statement. After digging through php.net docs I came up with this. I'm getting no error messages, but it is not updating the table. (I wrote a similar function to insert records which works fine.) Hopefully I'm just missing something simple, that someone can easily spot. :)

```
function updateRecord($table,$data,$fields,$id) {
    $mysqli = dbConnect();
    $fieldNames = array(); 
    $typeString = '';
    $placeholders = '';
    $params = array();

    foreach($fields as $fieldName => $fieldType) {
        $fieldNames[] = $fieldName; 
        $typeString .= $fieldType;
         $params[] = &$data[$fieldName];
    }
    $params[] = &$id;
    array_unshift($params,$typeString.'i');

    $fieldString = implode('=?,',$fieldNames).'=?';

    $query = 'update '.$table.' set '.$fieldString.' where id = ?';

    if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $params);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    dbDisconnect($mysqli);
}
```

`$_POST` is passed to `$data`, and an array like `('first_name' => 's', 'last_name' => 's', etc.)` is passed to `$fields`

I did a series of var_dumps do see what was happening and these are the results.

```
$params = array(17) { 
[0]=> string(16) "ssidssdsdssssssi" 
    [1]=> &string(4) "asdf" 
    [2]=> &string(0) "" 
    [3]=> &string(1) "0" 
    [4]=> &string(4) "0.00" 
    [5]=> &string(0) "" 
    [6]=> &string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    [7]=> &string(4) "0.00" 
    [8]=> &string(10) "0000-00-00" 
    [9]=> &string(4) "0.00" 
    [10]=> &string(0) "" 
    [11]=> &string(0) "" 
    [12]=> &string(26) "bc__1412690490_384x523.jpg" 
    [13]=> &string(0) "" 
    [14]=> &string(0) "" 
    [15]=> &string(0) "" 
    [16]=> &int(2) 
}
$fields = array(15) { 
    ["edition"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["ISBN"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["pages"]=> string(1) "i" 
    ["price"]=> string(1) "d" 
    ["pub_year"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["release_date"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["pre_order_price"]=> string(1) "d" 
    ["sale_start_date"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["sale_price"]=> string(1) "d" 
    ["kindle"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["image_1"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["image_2"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["paypal_script"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["pre_order_paypal_script"]=> string(1) "s" 
    ["sale_paypal_script"]=> string(1) "s" 
}   
$fieldnames = array(15) { 
    [0]=> string(7) "edition" 
    [1]=> string(4) "ISBN" 
    [2]=> string(5) "pages" 
    [3]=> string(5) "price" 
    [4]=> string(8) "pub_year" 
    [5]=> string(12) "release_date" 
    [6]=> string(15) "pre_order_price"
    [7]=> string(15) "sale_start_date" 
    [8]=> string(10) "sale_price" 
    [9]=> string(6) "kindle" 
    [10]=> string(7) "image_1" 
    [11]=> string(7) "image_2" 
    [12]=> string(13) "paypal_script" 
    [13]=> string(23) "pre_order_paypal_script" 
    [14]=> string(18) "sale_paypal_script" 
}
$query=string(232) "update editions set edition=?,ISBN=?,pages=?,price=?,pub_year=?,release_date=?,pre_order_price=?,sale_start_date=?,sale_price=?,kindle=?,image_1=?,image_2=?,paypal_script=?,pre_order_paypal_script=?,sale_paypal_script=? where id = ?"

$stmt = object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { //(var_dump placed after $stmt->execute)
    ["affected_rows"]=> int(0),
    ["insert_id"]=> int(0), 
    ["num_rows"]=> int(0),
    ["param_count"]=> int(16),
    ["field_count"]=> int(0),
    ["errno"]=> int(0),
    ["error"]=> string(0) "",
    ["error_list"]=> array(0) { },
    ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000",
    ["id"]=> int(1)
}
```

Comment: Can you post what your SQL looks like when you run this function?

Comment: Well, this is the query string that is sent to $mysqli->prepare($query): $query=string(232) "update editions set edition=?,ISBN=?,pages=?,price=?,pub_year=?,release_date=?,pre_order_price=?,sale_start_date=?,sale_price=?,kindle=?,image_1=?,image_2=?,paypal_script=?,pre_order_paypal_script=?,sale_paypal_script=? where id = ?"

Comment: After that point, I don't know how to find out what the query looks like when it is returned from stmt->bind_params

Comment: Solved! I knew it had to be something stupid and it wasn't in anything I posted. I was passing the wrong variable into the id field. There was no record with the id that was being passed in so I'm still not sure why I didn't see some sort of error.

Comment: Is `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` inside any of your files? That may be why it wasn't returning any errors, possibly.

Comment: No it isn't. I'll change that. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome Robin. Try it again using the original method you were doing that wasn't working. It should throw you an error/warning. Let me know.

Comment: Um no, not an error related to not being able to find the record.

Comment: I did get this:Notice: Undefined variable: _PHP_SELF in /homepages/9/d537385413/htdocs/update-edit-edition.php on line 32

Comment: Line 32 $html.='<form method="post" action="'.$_PHP_SELF.'" enctype = "multipart/form-data">';  The form reloads the page when it posts, which is working, so I'm surprised it's throwing an error.  Probably something else I don't understand.

Comment: If you're going to want to use `self`, you can just do `action=""` or `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"`

Comment: Actually, my other comment should have read as `action=\"\" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\"` if inside `echo`, yet it's safer to use `action=""` as there are apparently security issues using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`